# Why does CSS3 animation not work in my ASP.net website

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have an ASP.net website where I have the following...

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 99%; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="sample3" lang="is" class="sample3">

    <figure>
        <img src="../theImages/imgPra.png" width="160" height="160" alt="Specialty Profile" />
        <figcaption>Specialty Profile</figcaption>
    </figure>

<!--end sample3--></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sample3 figure {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: url('../theImages/preview4.jpg') fixed no-repeat;
}

.sample3 figcaption {
        position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 110px;
    bottom: -110px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(26,54,59,0.8);
    border: 3px solid rgba(62,116,126,0.6);
    line-height: 50px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0 2px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0 2px 8px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0 2px 8px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, left .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, left .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, left .5s ease-out;
    transition: bottom .5s ease-out, left .5s ease-out;
}

.sample3 figure:hover figcaption {
    left: -20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vas1watw/

It works fine in a regular webpage, but when I add it to my .net website, the ribbon is displayed without the animation.

How can I resolve the issue.

debug mode:

[image]

Comment: What browsers are you testing with? CSS is a client-side technology so the server technology is less relevant.

Comment: IE10... I ran the standard HTML page and it worked fine :/ When I check debug mode, the transition code are not there for the `class`.

Comment: I'm sure you've already checked but... is the CSS file being cached? Are any of the selectors or properties you are using being overridden somehow by any other files on your page?

Comment: It is funny, the `sample3` class isn't even being displayed in the debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code (HTML/CSS) were placed correctly in my site. IE just took a full day to refresh the page. I had to reset the IIS site which forced a refresh and it worked afterward.

Answer (score 2):

are you using sitemaster.if you using it place css on sitemaster

Comment: I added the code in the content page as well as the sitemaster style page which all the content page inherits but the same issue.

Comment: it pefectly working on asp.net website ,i just use your code.can you upload sitemater page code and child page code

Comment: please add css in head tag on mastersite

Comment: The css code only works if they are inline and the hover cannot be inline css :/

Comment: Why does IE does not load the class in the styles anyway? weird. I tried the same page in Chrome and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `ClientIDMode` property of the `@Page` directive. ASP.NET tends to auto adjust the client generated ids, which causes your CSS to nome handle `#sample3` selector since this Id will not exists in the HTML, unless that property is set to `Static`. Read more about [ClientIDMode on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I knew about so I added a class with the same name and it is not working still :/

Comment: Please, update your question with the changes so we can see if there's something wrong with the new `class`.

Comment: I updated with a screenshot for the debug mode. IE is not even seeing the class for some reason.

Comment: Where is your piece of CSS? Inside `pageStyle.css` or inside a `style` tag in `Maintenance.aspx`?

Comment: I placed in both just to see if it works. In chrome the same page works but in IE the styles doesn't even load. I cleared out cache like 3 times already. IE always has an issue. *SIGH*

Comment: Maybe there is some ASP.NET pre-processing of the style caused by anything you are using. Did you tried to open the CSS file with the IE Developer Toolbar to see if the content is exactly what you typed?

Comment: IE as always was acting "slow". Worked after a day. Thank you.